# Accessing Auxiliary Vectors C

Tags: c, loading, elf

I'm trying to access the [auxiliary vectors](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Auxiliary-Vector.html) in C using [the following code](http://articles.manugarg.com/aboutelfauxiliaryvectors.html):

```
  int main(int argc, char** argv, char* envp[]) {
  Elf64_auxv_t *auxv;
  while(*envp++ != NULL); 

  /*from stack diagram above: *envp = NULL marks end of envp*/
  int i = 0 ; 
  for (auxv = (Elf64_auxv_t *)envp; auxv->a_type != AT_NULL; auxv++)
    /* auxv->a_type = AT_NULL marks the end of auxv */
    {
      printf("%u %u %u \n", (auxv->a_type), AT_PLATFORM, i++);
      if( auxv->a_type == AT_PLATFORM)
        fprintf(stdout, "AT_PLATFORM is: %s\n", (auxv->a_un.a_val));
    }
  }
```

but the results I get are garbage. Running readelf shows me that I'm indeed running a 64 bit binary. I understand there's other ways to do it (getauxv in libc for example), but I'm curious as to why this particular way of doing it doesn't work

Thansk

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have some errors in your code which `gcc -Wall` will happily tell you:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <elf.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv, char* envp[]) {
  Elf64_auxv_t *auxv;
  while(*envp++ != NULL);

  /*from stack diagram above: *envp = NULL marks end of envp*/
  int i = 0 ;
  for (auxv = (Elf64_auxv_t *)envp; auxv->a_type != AT_NULL; auxv++)
    /* auxv->a_type = AT_NULL marks the end of auxv */
  {
    printf("%lu %u %u \n", (auxv->a_type), AT_PLATFORM, i++);
    if( auxv->a_type == AT_PLATFORM)
      printf("AT_PLATFORM is: %s\n", ((char*)auxv->a_un.a_val));
  }
}
```

The above code works for me (it prints `AT_PLATFORM is: x86_64`).

Comment: The char**/char* error was a mistake when copying the code onto stack overflow. Even with %lu, i still get garbage output. Specifically

Comment: What platform exactly?  Compiler, OS, processor, etc.